# Unable to insert and ENCRYPT_AES() in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, aes, db2-400

DB2: Version 7.3  Product: DB2 UDB for AS/400 v07.03.0000 V7R3m0

> Client: IBM i Access Client Solutions (64-bit) Version: 1.1.8.8 Build
> id: 1380 2021-09-13 13:47:59
> C:\Users\Public\IBM\ClientSolutions\acsbundle.jar
>
> java.version: 11.0.11 java.vendor: AdoptOpenJDK java.home:
> C:\Users\Public\IBM\ClientSolutions\Start_Programs\Windows_x86-64\jdk-11.0.11+9-jre
> java.fullversion: 11.0.11+9 JRE 11 Windows 10 amd64-64-Bit Compressed
> References 20210421_976  OpenJ9   - b4cc246d9 OMR      - 162e6f729 JCL
>
> - 7796c80419 based on jdk-11.0.11+9

I am trying to insert AES encrypted data. I seem to be able to do it by first inserting and then updating the new record using ENCRYPT_AES but I would prefer to insert all at once since I think it will be more efficient.

```
create table POS_CCR_SIMPLE (
  SIMPLE VARCHAR(10000) FOR BIT DATA
);
```

Testing that the following works to make sure our table works the way we expect:

```
insert into POS_CCR_SIMPLE (SIMPLE)
values (x'123456');
```

We want to insert using ENCRYPT_AES(), but the following does not work:

`insert into POS_CCR_SIMPLE (SIMPLE) values (ENCRYPT_AES('If you can read this Request, it is decrypted.', 'key123'))`

DB2 replies:

> [ 02/26/2023, 11:29:26 AM ]  Run Selected...   insert into
> POS_CCR_SIMPLE (SIMPLE) values (ENCRYPT_AES('Inserted Request',
> 'key123'))
> SQL State: 02000 Vendor Code: 100
> Message: [SQL0100] Row not found for INSERT. Cause . . . . . :
> One of the following
> conditions has occurred: -- If this is a FETCH statement, no more rows
> satisfy the selection values (end of file).  The name of the cursor is
> INSERT and the result set identifier is 0. If the result set
> identifier is non-zero, the result table for this cursor was being
> accessed as a stored procedure result set. -- If this is a FETCH
> statement for a scrollable cursor, a record was not found.  If NEXT
> was specified, end of file was reached.  If PRIOR was specified, the
> beginning of the file was reached.  If RELATIVE was specified, either
> the beginning of file or the end of file was reached, depending on the
> value specified.  If FIRST or LAST was specified, then no records
> satisfy the selection criteria. The name of the cursor is INSERT. --
> If this is an embedded SELECT statement, no rows satisfy the selection
> values. -- If this is an UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, or MERGE statement,
> no rows satisfy the subselect, WHERE clause, or MERGE criteria.  No
> rows were updated, inserted, or deleted. -- If SKIP LOCKED DATA is
> specified, no available rows qualified for return. Recovery  . . . :  
> No recovery is necessary.

The following works, insert first and then update using ENCRYPT_AES but it is a 2-step process which we would like to avoid:

```
insert into POS_CCR_SIMPLE (SIMPLE) values (x'123456');

update POS_CCR_SIMPLE set SIMPLE = ENCRYPT_AES('If you can read this Request, it is decrypted.', 'key123');

select DECRYPT_CHAR(SIMPLE, 'key123') from POS_CCR_SIMPLE;
```

Goal is to perform this all in a single INSERT. Is it possible?

Comment: For the insert statement that embeds the ENCRYPT_AES, how are you submitting this statement? Are there other statements in the same transaction or batch?  Have you tried submitting that single insert from a different tool ? Are you sure the insert statement is exactly as shown in your question (because SQLCODE 100 is not possible from a plain insert , but is possible with a statement like `insert into... select from...` or other searched queried.

Comment: @mao, I am using IBM i Access Client, details added to OP.
I also added the complete output so you can see what my client actually executed. It is a single transaction.

I have also tried JDBC with ever worse results.
I cannot even run the update part in JDBC.

Comment: @mao I have added my attempt with JDBC.

Comment: The java error is just programming related so won't get into that. Suggest to simplify only to investigate more. Try a table with a single column for bit data, and a single insert with the encrypt_aes() in it. If it fails, I would trace the i access driver (see docs).  I don't have access to as400 to recreate.

Comment: @mao Replaced table and example in the OP with a much simpler example. Same result.

Comment: The statement that fails on your machine does not on mine. Check DB2 PTF level using `select
  PTF_GROUP_ID,
  PTF_GROUP_TITLE,
  PTF_GROUP_LEVEL_INSTALLED,
  PTF_GROUP_LEVEL_AVAILABLE
from
  systools.group_ptf_currency P
where
    PTF_GROUP_ID in ('SF99703')`

Comment: @nfgl DB2 says:  `SF99703   SF99703 730 DB2 for IBM i   32   32`

Comment: The inserts worked for me without modification. Are you sure you didn't have a typo in your attempt?

Comment: Does `insert into POS_CCR_SIMPLE (SIMPLE) select ENCRYPT_AES('If you can read this Request, it is decrypted.', 'key123') from sysibm.sysdummy1` work ?

Comment: @nfgl  **Yes.  That is it! Thank you very much.**
Is this behavior specific to iSeries or our version of DB2?

I wonder now if this will work using JDBC...

Comment: The problem you have is really strange, should not happen. I suggest you open a ticket.

Comment: @nfgl Our IBM Admin is doing so. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: **Solution:** IBM determined that we were missing a record from QSYS2/QSQPTABL.
After that record was restored, the insert statement with ENCRYPT_AES works.